# Is there a simple way to access the REPL history (e.g. as a list) from within GHCi?

Tags: haskell, read-eval-print-loop, ghci

Other REPLs, [e.g. Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Commands-For-History.html), have dedicated commands for browsing the command history. I find that quite handy (though whenever I use such a feature I ask myself, *why didn't I properly define that command in a file in the first place*?).

GHCi seems to have no such feature, and I think it probably shouldn't – such interactivity would make endevours like control from Emacs more troublesome than they are already.

However, it sounds like a rather trivial task to simply fetch *the entire history*, and then use ordinary Haskell to browse it. Has anything like that been implemented anywhere yet?

Comment: A related question would be how to get the output of commands like `:browse`, or of tab-auto-completion, into a usable Haskell list.

Comment: This is about adding `history :: IO [String]` to GHCi, right? AFAIK, there's no such feature. For `:browse`, I wonder if `Distribution.HaskellSuite.Modules` can do.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm looking for. Something like `searchHistory :: (String -> Bool) -> IO ()` would perhaps be even more useful (to prepend a matching command "forward" so it can then be accessed and executed with up-arrow), though that idea does seem a bit procedural/destructive.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: You're aware that there's reverse-search? Ctrl+R, as in bash. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Zeta: Whoa, it's as simple as that?? Well, I should have tried that myself shouldn't I... wonder, should I close the question, or rephrase it to focus on string-reading history or other stuff, or will you just post `ctrl+r` as an answer?

Comment: @leftaroundabout As per my answer that I posted about the same time you made your last comment, you can actually get the history from previous GHCi sessions as a `[String]` if that's what you really want, but `CTRL+R` is definitely the more useful route.  I use it pretty much constantly, particularly because it works in more than just GHCi, bash and IPython support it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do this that's more cross-platform way that could be developed into a nice little package to load in a .ghci file or something, but the quick and dirty way using `haskeline` is pretty simple.  You can just read in the `ghci_history` file for your system, mine is located at `C:/Users/bheklilr/AppData/Roaming/ghc/ghci_history`, but I believe on a *nix system it should be at `~/.ghci_history`.  Pick whichever is appropriate for your system.

```
> import System.Console.Haskeline.History
> hist <- fmap $ readHistory "path/to/ghci_history"
> putStrLn $ unlines hist
```

Unfortunately, at least for me, it seems that the history file is not updated until GHCi exits, so for a particular session `hist` should be the same (provided you only have one instance of GHCi).  This is a pretty limited API in my opinion, I think it wouldn't be too hard to dump the history on each command or at least every couple commands, but this is not done.

Alternatively, you can use `CTRL-R` and a handful of other commands to search your history, it's a lot more useful.  It's especially useful because it'll search for matching subtext.

Comment: I'll still accept this as answer to the question as I phrased it (though, as you said yourself, `ctrl+r` is a much better solution for the actual _problem_ at hand).